# MySQL: Return row if joined table contains least one match

Tags: mysql, inner-join

[image: Table struct]

(Main table *id* equal to *jid*. Join based on that.)
**The 1st** item has got **2 row** in the join table. /That's great./
**But 3rd** item has got **no row** in join table.
**The question**: How can i ignore those items that has got no joined rows? **IN ONE QUERY.**

I tried the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM mainTable AS mainT
LEFT JOIN joinTable AS joinT ON mainT.id=joinT.jid
WHERE COUNT(joinT.id) > 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`, and remove the `WHERE` clause.